How to get all data in hoola webhook to nodejs server
I am currently working on a project using react-native and expressjs to make an affiliate app, using sapo's webhook. Have any of you ever made webhooks or sapo webhooks? I need a little information on how to use it.
Thanks you!
I was try to read and use webhook sapo. I want to get data from website webhook
